# Replacement macros for Netbeans

Tags: regex, netbeans, macros

Is it possible to write replacement macros for NetBeans?

I need to replace `function is_active` with `function isActive`. It seems that is not possible with short regex.

So I wonder is it possible to write such macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crazy macros code....

We cannot use find properly, so I decieded to use `find-selection`

```
caret-begin            
"function[^(]*_[a-z]"  
selection-begin-line   
find-selection
remove-selection
find

# there is no loop, so you need to repeat this lines many-many times (too many may hang your IDE)
caret-begin
find-next
caret-forward    
caret-backward   
delete-previous
to-upper-case
```

To use this macros you need to set the focus on a document and have turned on regex find option.

Warning, could spoil your code.

Comment: I've found that using find / replace and history to be more easy